# Why the VS didn’t close my app in emulator when I closed the vs code?

Tags: flutter, dart

Afternoon , I use VS code for Flutter-Dart Mobile application, I have a problem with VS code , when i test my app in android studio emulator the app successfully run but when i finished my test the emulator didn’t close the app automatically, “vs code have this feature before “ but now it doesn’t work.

I’ve checked the “hot reload” and it is active